# FxFlexFill in firefox not working properly

Tags: firefox, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem with FxFlex and Firefox that I'm not able to solve.

What I want to do is a div that fill the screen and header with 40px height and the content with the rest of the height.

It works in chrome, my screen has 982px, the header has 40px and the content 942px.

In Firefox the screen has 982px, the header 40px and the content 982px, so, it doesn't show all the content.

this is my html:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column">

   <header fxFlex="40px">
   </header>

   <content fxFlex fxLayout="row">
   </content>

</div>
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it, the solution is include height in second fxFlex:

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column">

  <header fxFlex="40px">
  </header>

  <content fxFlex="calc(100%-40px)" fxLayout="row">
  </content>

</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per the Angular Wiki the definition of fxFlexFill as:

> fxFlexFill:
> Maximizes width and height of element in a layout container

What is not mentioned is if the parent container or the elements in the layout container doesn't have any height, it get height: 0px. So you need always have some parent/child node to have a height which is not in percentage.